# Getting all the installed color schemes in Vim

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm using vim to edit a php. I would like to get all the installed color schemes in Vim. I know that some members have asked this question, but the accepted solutions there did not help.

I tried:

`:colorscheme` then <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

No colors shows up when I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Should I install something to get the colorscheme work?

Answer (score 4):

Color schemes are stored under your `'runtimepath'` + `/colors/*.vim`. e.g. The default scheme is store at `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/default.vim`.

Two ways of getting a list of all colorschemes:

- `:echo globpath(&rtp, 'colors/*.vim')`
- `:colorscheme` followed by <kbd>space</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

If you are not getting a list of colors then you may want to check if to make sure you don't have a tiny version of vim. You can check this by running `:version`. You can also run `:echo has('eval')` to make sure you can run colorschemes.

For more information see:

```
:h 'runtimepath'
:h :colors
:h globpath(
:h cmdline-completion
:h c_CTRL-D
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to turn the syntax on
try:
 `:syntax on`

Answer (score 0):

My system: Debian bullseye (11), vim `:version` states 8.1
Type this inside vim ..

`:colorscheme` + `desert` + `Enter` sets color scheme to "desert" (for this session/opened-file only)
`:colo desert` Is just shortcut to colorscheme, my favorite decent one and available on any linux I used so far. Default darkblue, or what it is has comment lines almost unreadably dark. IMHO bad choice of default one.

`:colorscheme` + `Tab` cycles through schemes a-z
`:colorscheme` + `Shift-Tab` cycles through schemes z-a
`:colorscheme` + `Ctrl-d` show all schemes

```
:colorscheme
blue       default    desert     evening    koehler    murphy     peachpuff  shine      torte
darkblue   delek      elflord    industry   morning    pablo      ron        slate      zellner
```

Alternatively see them as preinstalled files: `$ ls –l /usr/share/vim/vim*/colors`

To make it more permanent and do not need to set colorscheme in every opened document ('desert' is just selected colorscheme here):
`echo "colorscheme desert" >> .vimrc`

More color schemes can be found (with examples) on pages like https://vimcolorschemes.com/ and so on GitHub as .vim files.
There might be specific installation options per your VIM version, Wiki of the package should help.